# Favicon does not work - HTML

Tags: html, favicon

I am trying to use a favicon for my site but its not working. The site is just a test site and I am using WAMP server. I am using a 16x X 16x .ico image as the favicon.

Here is my code :

```
<link rel="Shortcut Icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

How can I make this work?
Thanks!

Comment: You spelled shortcut wrong. You should also just stick to the default `/favicon.ico` for name and location.

Comment: @JohnConde Thanks! I corrected the spelling and also renamed `icon.ico` to `favicon.ico`. But its not working! Please help!

Comment: You also need to make sure it's an actual ICO image. Not just a GIF or something with the file extension changed.
There is no need for any additions to your code either.  As long as it resides on the root for your site, it will appear automatically.

Comment: @durbnpoisn Initially, it was a png image. I just renamed the file extension. Sorry if its too dumb but I am new to web development.

Comment: In which directories are the icon and html file you are referencing it from?

Comment: Well, there's your problem.  There are converters out there where you can generate the correct format.  Do that, name it right, and drop it in the root.

Comment: @DroidFan After changing the code empty the browser cache correctly

Comment: @durbnpoisn Thanks! I'll do that. My html file and the favicon image are in the same main folder.

Answer (score 3):

Your code seems fine.
If the favicon is a png type image, it'll not work in older versions of Chrome. However it'll work just fine in FireFox. Also, don't forget to clear your browser cache while working on such things. Many a times, code is just fine, but cache is the real culprit.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where the favicon image is located, relative to the file you are referencing it from. If the favicon is at the site root, you would write:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

**EDIT**: Keep it as a png.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="http://eg.com/favicon.png">
```

Comment: Thanks! But I kept it as a png the very first time I tried. It didn't work and hence I changed the extension to .ico

Comment: .png is supported by most browsers. It's used often. Here's the [w3 spec](http://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon)

Answer (score 1):

Adding answer because after comments, this appear correct.

Name the image "favicon.ico".  Make sure it's in the root of the site.  Make sure that it is a valid, .ICO image, and not just a GIF or a PNG with the extenstion changed.

Comment: Not for nuthin', but I see this issue pop up from time to time here.  There really needs to be emphasis put on the correct file type.  You can use a PNG, if you'd like, and it IS supported by most browsers.  But if you're going to go that route, you should deffinitely have a valid ICO also.  Then there is pretty much no chance of it being missed.